# Getting output of shell commands in Python (cron)?

Tags: python, shell, cron

I'm trying to write a script which detects my current wifi connection and starts a socks proxy on my local computer.
The script itself works fine when I execute it by myself. Since I want everything to be automatically, I was thinking of using crontab. The only problem is that crontob itself doesn't have output or so, therefore the methods return an empty string.

Does anyone have a solution for this? My script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import re, os

location = Popen(['networksetup', '-getcurrentlocation'], stdout=PIPE).stdout.read().split('\n')[0]

ssid = ''
for item in Popen(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport', '-I'], stdout=PIPE).stdout.read().splitlines():
    if ' SSID' in item:
        ssid = item.strip().split(': ')[-1] 

if location != 'xyz' and ssid == 'abc':
    # start socks proxy
    pass

elif location == 'xyz' and ssid != 'abc':
    # kill socks proxy
    pass

print location, '|', ssid
```

I'm working on Mac OS 10.10.1 if somebody wants to know.

Comment: What does your crontab file look like?

Comment: */10 * * * * python /Users/Exceen/Scripts/autoproxy.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy `Popen` should return process output both when you run it manyally and via cron.

1. Try to redirect stderr to stdout inside Popend: `stderr=sys.stdout.buffer` (python3) and read the output, why command can't be exectued.
2. Probably your script is run as `root` (if you edited /etc/crontab), try to change line to
   `*/10 * * * * Exceen python /Users/Exceen/Scripts/autoproxy.py`
3. Try to write full path to `networksetup` binary. Cron job can have different `$PATH`, missing /usr/bin/ (or wherever networksetup is)